# How to build a function with multiple fat arrows clauses in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I am coming to Javascript from a functional background.

I am imagining something like this to compute the factorial of 3:

```
var Function1 =    
{
  (0) => 1,
  (1) => 1,
  (n) => n*Function1(n-1)
}

document.write(Function1(3),"<br/>")
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there something similar to my example in javascript that computes 6 using **fat arrow** notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in the descriptive/declarative way in JS, but you can listen to the value of the parameter and react accordingly:

```
var Function1 = (n) => {
  if (n === 0) return 1;
  if (n === 1) return 1;
  return Function1(n-1)*n;
}
document.write(Function1(3),"<br/>"); // 6
```

Another way would be to return a [curried function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying):

```
var Function1 = (n) => {
  if (n === 0) return () => 1;
  if (n === 1) return () => 1;
  return () => Function1(n-1)()*n;
}
document.write(Function1(3)(),"<br/>"); // 6
```

Mind the second function call here `Function1(3)()`.

Your example could be shortened a bit with a ternary operator, but it works against maintainability and readability:

```
var Function1 = (n) => [0, 1].includes(n) ? 1 : Function1(n-1)*n;
document.write(Function1(3),"<br/>"); // 6
```

Comment: your second method using currying returns NaN for arguments greater than 1

Comment: Thankyou for great answer anyhow

Comment: `NaN` is fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simplified "one-line" alternative using `Number` constructor:

```
var Function1 = (n) => { return Number(n === 0 || n === 1) || Function1(n-1)*n; };

console.log(Function1(0));  // 1
console.log(Function1(1));  // 1
console.log(Function1(4));  // 24
```